# VS2017 debugging error: Evaluating the function timed out and needed to be aborted...

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

when I debug code, I often get this popup in Visual Studio 2017, that prevents me from evaluating objects.

[image]

I clicked on Help button and read the instructions what to do, however none of the options they suggested, which is basically - to disable all property evaluation, that makes debugging useless since I do want to see the state of the object or the collection.

**Is there any way to solve this? Thanks.**

Comment: Do you use the latest 15.7.4 version? Please also check that whether it is related to the option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" under Tools->Options->Debugging.

Comment: I have 15.7.3... will update now to see if it helps

Comment: If you get any update, feel free to share it here, but if it still has this issue after you use the latest version, to really repro this issue, you could share a simple sample here using one drive.

Comment: I got an update but the issue still exists, most likely it depends on a size and complexity of the object I am trying to evaluate

Comment: If it still has this issue, like this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400276/vs2017-which-function-causing-breakpoint-timeout?rq=1, I also suggest you report this feedback to the VS product team directly though the VS IDE.

Comment: Related posts - [Debugging issue in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48020427/465053) & [Visual Studio 2017 Debug Error: To prevent an unsafe abort when evaluating the function *.toString all threads where allowed to run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52187355/465053)

Answer (score 1):

Check this option:

> Debug > Options > "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"

This is not ideal. From the docs "Use Managed Compatability Mode":

> Replaces the default debugging engine with a legacy version to enable
>   these scenarios:
>
> You are using a .NET Framework language other than C#, VB, or F#
>   that provides its own Expression Evaluator (this includes C++/CLI).
>
> You want to enable Edit and Continue for C++ projects while mixed mode debugging.
>   Note that choosing Managed Compatibility mode disables some features that are implemented only in the default debugging engine.